# An unhandled exception occurred: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I was migrating from Angular version 11 to 14 and In the end this error came when I was trying to run or build the application, after successfull migration.

> ng serve

I wanted to serve the application, then I got this error

An unhandled exception occurred: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null See `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ISIjXp\angular-errors.log` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

It was a circular dependency issue in the **package.json** file

**In angular version 11**

"@angular/http": "7.2.16",

But in Angular version 14, http module is present inside **@angular/common** so we don't need **@angular/http**

**Replace**
"@angular/http": "7.2.16",

**With**
"@angular/common": "^14.3.0",

I had also changed these
"@schematics/angular": "^14.2.13",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
"webpack": "^5.0.0",

This solved my issue.